# include excel in .jar

Tags: java, excel

I need to know what is the best way to export excel file into my .jar code.

I used GetDesktop open file statement, and that works good when I run it inside of Eclipse IDE. But when I export my code into a .JAR, the excel sheet will not open, it will not do anything.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
 try { Desktop desktop = null;
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
}
    desktop.open(new File("Resources/pics/chart 2.xls"));
} catch (IOException ioe) {
      ioe.printStackTrace();
}}
```

I have a picture image in a jframe, and I have 2 buttons, inside of the picture, for the user to click on. Depends on which button they click on, I need that certain excel file to open. Just for viewing purposes, no editing is involved. I tried using apache POI, but the excel file did not open at all, but when I use the code above at least it opens in eclipse. I see that there is others with the same problem, but mine I need it to just open excel not edit.
thanks

Comment: You need to copy/extract the excel spread from the Jar to the local drive - remember, a Jar file is just a zip file

Comment: I am trying to make my program as complete as I can, so that if I run it on another PC I do not have to copy the excel files on to the local drive. I seen that some other programmers did open excel files thru there programs. I am hoping that it could be done.

Comment: Sorry correction, some other programmers extracted information from there excel files, but I am trying to open the excel file.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter, Excel can't read the embedded resource, it MUST be extracted to the local computer

Comment: I am just wondering why it opens inside of eclipse, but not when you export it?

Comment: Probably because eclipse is using the `src` path and not the Jar

Comment: If I was to put the excel file on the local drive, would I use the same try catch block and just change the destination? How would you do it?

Comment: Yes - the location would be depend on where you extracted the file to

Comment: Thanks that work good. Not what I wanted but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

You must copy it out of the jar. You can get an inputstream using `InputStream in = ClassYouAreIn.class.getResource("someFile.xls")`. Here is an example:

```
try (InputStream in = ClassYouAreIn.class.getResource("someFile.xls")) {
    // copy it here, for example using:
    Files.copy(in, Paths.get("somefile.xls"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

NB: Your catch code is really bad: exceptions contain 4 interesting bits of information (type, message, stacktrace, causal chain) and you're chucking 3 of the 4 things, AND you are causing a cascade of errors by not aborting. You should always just throw them onwards (put `throws IOException` on this method) unless you have an *ACTUAL* strategy to deal with it (and logging / printing it is not dealing with it!).

Comment: I tried it, and Eclipse is trying to change from getResource to getResourceAsStream, is that correct? and I do have a throws IOException in my main method. But even with getResourceAsStream it did not output anything.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. THat will output something or throw an error, if you don't see an error you're catching the exception and ignoring it someplace.